# Как правильно пишется: "рекламная компания" или "рекламная кампания"?

Tags: орфография, лексика, выбор-слов

Как правильно пишется: "рекламная к**о**мпания" или "рекламная к**а**мпания"?

Answer (score 7):

Кампания - не военная стратегия, а обозначние какого-то масштабного мероприятия, действия. Например, "предвыборная кампания" или "кампания по борьбе с наркоманией".
Слово "компания" обозначает любую общность людей: "компания друзей", "акционерная компания" и т.д.

Answer (score 6):

Контекст бы не помешал.
Рекламная кампания - это мероприятие (по рекламе чего-либо).
Рекламная компания - предприятие (занимающееся рекламой).

Comment: Учавствовала в мозговых штурмах и рекламный компаниях.

Comment: Это резюме? Ну здесь-то "кампания". Вы же *участвовали* в кампаниях, которые организовывала какая-то фирма, *не являющаяся* рекламной компанией.

Answer (score 5):

Кампания - это работа, проводимая в определённый период для осуществления какой-л. важной общественно-политической или хозяйственной цели. Рекламная кАмпания, избирательная к., посевная к.

А кОмпания - это группа людей, объединение : собраться кОмпанией близких друзей, акционерная кОмпания.

Comment: Спасибо. Я правильно вас поняла, что надо писать (рекламная кампания)?

Comment: Да, рекламная кАмпания!

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню, тут всё зависит от текста и смысла: кампания - военная стратегия, план действия на войне (что-то типа того); а если коллектив или команда (например, сотрудников), или друзья (в компании друзей), то тогда компания. Вроде, как-то так!..

Answer (score 0):

Для лучшего понимания и запоминания (О или А) советую обратиться к английским аналогам: cOmpany, cAmpaign. Или французским, латинским - кому что ближе.

Comment: Ошибаетесь, "campaign" пришло в английский из французского ("campagne"), а "company" — из старофранцузского.

Comment: @Артем, Вы отчасти правы. Если верить этимологическому словарю, то компания происходит от латинского соmраniа (сообщество), а кампания  - от французского саmраgnе (поход, массовое мероприятие). Но так как английский более распространен, а посоветовал обратиться к английским "аналогам" (скажем так вместо того, чтобы утверждать, что эти слова пришли из английского). Впрочем, можно обратиться и к французким словам. Это не меняет сути моего совета.

Comment: Да, так лучше, а вообще идея Ваша мне понравилась, и я совершенно не хотел придираться, просто уточнил (а тон ("ошибаетесь") просто случайно получился, возможно, немножко недовольным или критикующим). Простите, если резковато получилось.

Comment: it's all right :)

Answer (score 0):

Слово *компания* с буквой О в корне синонимично словам *ватага, гурьба, толпа, куча* (прост.) Например: они всей компанией отправились на речку.

А слово *кампания* с буквой А в корне синонимично слову *акция*. Например: военная кампания, избирательная кампания.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечая коротко на вопрос топикстартера:
Рекламная кОмпания, которая занимается рекламной кАмпанией.